# Exception calling "Script" with "0" argument(s): "Script failed for Database

Tags: docker, powershell, ubuntu

I'm getting this error on SMO Script and not sure what is wrong. And also I'm running this powershell script on a Ubuntu Docker Container.

```
Exception calling "Script" with "0" argument(s): "Script failed for Database 'TestDatabase' ."
```

Code:

```
foreach($x in $tb){

        Write-Host $x.Name
        $dbase = $x.Name

        ## GENERATE DB AND OBJECT SCRIPT FROM SOURCE SERVER.
        $nameConve = "$($destinationSVR)_$($dbase)"
        Write-Host $nameConve

        $SQLSrvObj = new-object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server" $sourceConn
               
        $SQLSrvObj.Information `
        | Select-Object parent, platform, product, productlevel, `
        OSVersion, Edition, version, HostPlatform, HostDistribution `
        | Format-List;
        
        $dbs = $SQLSrvObj.databases
        Write-Host $dbs
        $res = $dbs[$dbase].Script()

        Write-Host $res

     
    }
```

Looks like I'm getting an error on this part but not sure why.

```
$res = $dbs[$dbase].Script()
```

Thanks!

Additional Error Details.

```
System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException:
Exception calling "Script" with "0" argument(s): 
"Script failed for Database 'Bookie'. " ---> Microsoft.
SqlServer.Management.Smo.FailedOperationException: 
Script failed for Database 'Bookie'.  ---> 
System.TypeInitializationException: The type 
initializer for 
'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.TypeConverters' 
threw an exception. ---> 
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception 
has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> 
System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException: 

Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.LocalizableResources.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.
```

Comment: Please post the error message in its entirety (looks like it's been truncated)

Comment: It's just the Database Name is truncated. I posted it. That's why the error is confusing.